# SQL - select only newest record with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have been trying to get some data off our database but got stuck when I needed to only get the newest file upload for each file type. I have done this before using the WHERE clause but this time there is an extra table involved that is needed to determine the file type.

My query looks like this so far and i am getting six records for this user (2x filetypeNo4 and 4x filetypeNo2).

```
 SELECT db_file.fileID
    ,db_profile.NAME
    ,db_applicationFileType.fileTypeID
    ,> db_file.dateCreated
FROM db_file
LEFT JOIN db_applicationFiles 
    ON db_file.fileID = db_applicationFiles.fileID
LEFT JOIN db_profile 
    ON db_applicationFiles.profileID = db_profile.profileID
LEFT JOIN db_applicationFileType 
    ON db_applicationFiles.fileTypeID = > > db_applicationFileType.fileTypeID
WHERE db_profile.profileID IN ('19456')
    AND db_applicationFileType.fileTypeID IN ('2','4')
```

I have the WHERE clause looking like this which is not working:

```
(db_file.dateCreated IS NULL 
OR db_file.dateCreated = (
    SELECT MAX(db_file.dateCreated)
    FROM db_file left join
db_applicationFiles on db_file.fileID = db_applicationFiles.fileID
    WHERE db_applicationFileType.fileTypeID = db_applicationFiles.FiletypeID
))
```

Sorry I am a noob so this may be really simple, but I just learn this stuff as I go on my own..

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result..

Comment: not directly related to your question but `left join db_applicationFiles` with a `WHERE db_applicationFileType.fileTypeID = db_applicationFiles.FiletypeID` will treat this table as `inner join`. Not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ff.fileID,
  pf.NAME,
  ff.fileTypeID,
  ff.dateCreated
FROM db_profile pf
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 af.fileTypeID, df.dateCreated, df.fileID
  FROM db_file df
  INNER JOIN db_applicationFiles af
  ON df.fileID = af.fileID
  WHERE af.profileID = pf.profileID
    AND af.fileTypeID IN ('2','4')
  ORDER BY create_date DESC
) ff
WHERE pf.profileID IN ('19456')
```

And it looks like all of your joins are actually `INNER`. Unless there may be profile without files (that's why `OUTER` apply instead of `CROSS`).

Answer (score 0):

What about an obvious:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM db_file ORDER BY dateCreated DESC) AS files1 
GROUP BY fileTypeID ;
```

Comment: The point of this code is not very obvious actually. Not sure if this will happen for 100% but optimizer may totally ignore that `order by` in _subquery_ without _top_.